# What is the most efficient way to make data going to a ostream to go to a array of bytes?

Tags: c++, stringstream, ostream

I have a function that I need to call which takes an ostream.

What I want is the data in a char array, a char*.

So what I do is the following to copy the ostream data into imageBytes. The problem is, this seems inefficient to me, I just want to get data into a char[ONE_MEGABYTES]. Outputting it to the stringstream seems to be a very indirect way to do it. How could I do it more efficiently?

```
    #define ONE_MEGABYTE 1048576

    volatile char* imageBytes = new char[ONE_MEGABYTE];

    stringstream pngImageStringStream(ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
    image.write_stream(pngImageStringStream);
    imageLength = pngImageStringStream.tellp();
    memcpy( (void*)imageBytes, (void*)pngImageStringStream.str().c_str(), imageLength);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the string returned by `pngImageStringStream.str()`? Why does it have to be in this array? If `s` is the result then you can use `&s[0]` just like a C array because the string data is contiguous.

Comment: If I use the string returned by .str() isn't it the case that the string is created in memory, and then it will be free'ed, so it must be created and destroyed, there-by having an inefficiency of creating and destroying a large string object.

Comment: You're doing the same thing with allocating your array. Both need a large amount of memory.

Comment: Yes sure, but I will re-use the imageBytes over and over whenever the code below the declaration of imageBytes is called, there-by writing from the ostream to imageBytes over and over.

Comment: OK. You could look into `strstream` (different to `stringstream`) but it's deprecated. It works with `char` arrays. I don't have any experience with it though.

Comment: Can you show me the `write_stream` function please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be to use `read`:

```
pngImageStringStream.read(imageBytes, imageLength);
```